# Нужна ли запятая в союзе "вместо того чтобы" в начале предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

> Вместо того(,) чтобы покупать новый дом или продавать старый, можете
> сделать ремонт в этом старом доме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант без запятой предпочтителен (как минимум).
В начале предложения союзы обычно не расчленяются.

> В) Если придаточная часть предшествует главной – запятая ставится
> только после всего придаточного предложения.
>
> С тех пор как вечный судия // Мне дал всеведанье пророка, // В очах
> людей читаю я // Страницы злобы и порока. М. Лермонтов, Пророк. **Вместо
> того чтобы** становиться толпой против толпы, люди расходятся врозь,
> нападают поодиночке. Л. Толстой, Война и мир. В случае если
> Исполнитель не выполнил своих обязательств в сроки, указанные в
> настоящем Договоре, Заказчик вправе расторгнуть Договор.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3

И вот еще.

> Если союз стоит в абсолютном начале предложения, то расчленять его не
> рекомендуется, например: *После того как вчера вечером Павел Алексеевич
> похвалил её дочку, она стала ей гораздо больше нравиться (Л. Улицкая.
> Казус Кукоцкого).* Достаточно поставить одну запятую в конце зависимой
> части.

https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=12&chapterid=68

ПС. Не считаю последний сайт особо авторитетным, но в данном случае они приводят четкую формулировку итого, что в общем-то известно и из других источников.

Comment: @JKlen  *По второй ссылке не нашел приведенной цитаты* - спасибо, поправил. Остальное не комментирую, не вижу, как это может улучшить мой ответ.

Comment: @JKlen а, понял. Вы формально подошли к изложенному "грамотой" тексту и решили, что формулировка не покрывает всех случаев союза в начале предложения? Это не так. Именно потому, что в начале предложения такой союз принадлежит (возможно за редчайшими исключениями) придаточной части, он и не разделяется запятой. Подумайте, иначе получалось бы, что придаточное часть отрывает половину союза (вместо того) от главной части. Это очень страно, не находите?

Comment: @JKlen Какие 4 примера-то, ась? Есть примеры, где запятая требуется в силу дополнительных условий, не отрицаю. Но это никак не спасает от того факта, что ***как правило*** не расчленяются.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118902/discussion-between-behemothus-and-jklen).